# The default connection string for Membership framework in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, connection-string

What is the default connection string for ASP.NET applications?
I have written a simple ASP.NET application which uses Membership framework, but I haven't specified "connectionString" in my web.config. Nevertheless, the application is able to connect to a database. What database it connects to? What's the connection string for it and where it is located in my filesystem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default generated connection-string for a ASP.NET MVC3 application is

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The file is located in the `App_Data` folder in the websites root